# Solving Polynomial equation using javascript

Tags: javascript, polynomial-math, equation-solving

I have a polynomial equation which needs to be solved programmatically. The equation is as below.

```
x/207000 + (x/1349)^(1/0.282) = (260)^2/(207000*x)
```

I need to solve for x. I am using javascript for this. Is there any library in javascript which can solve mathematical equation?

Comment: `x/207000 + (x/1349)^(1/0.282) = (260)^2/(207000*x)` is not a polynomial equation because `(260)^2/(207000*x)` is not a polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

Some computer algebra systems in JavaScript can solve systems of polynomial equations. Using [Algebrite](http://algebrite.org/), you can solve an equation like this one:

`roots(x^2 + 2x = 4)`

The roots of this equation are `[-1-5^(1/2),-1+5^(1/2)]`.

It's also possible to solve systems of polynomial equations using [Nerdamer](https://github.com/jiggzson/nerdamer). Its documentation includes this example:

```
var sol = nerdamer.solveEquations('x^3+8=x^2+6','x');
console.log(sol.toString());
//1+i,-i+1,-1
```

Answer (score 2):

There are JavaScript solvers out there that will numerically solve your problem. The non-linear solver that I know of is [Ceres.js](https://github.com/Pterodactylus/Ceres.js). Here is an example adapted to your question. The first thing we have to do is rearrange to the form F(x)=0.

x0 = 184.99976046503917

```js
async function ceresSolve(jsonSystem) {
const {Ceres} = await import('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Pterodactylus/Ceres.js@latest/dist/ceres.min.js');
let solver = new Ceres()
let results = await solver.run(jsonSystem);
console.log(results.x) //Print solver results
console.log(results.report) //Print solver report
}

let jsonSystem = {
"variables": {
    "x": {
        "guess": 1,
    },
},
"functions": [
    "x/207000+(x/1349)^((1/0.282))-((260)^2/(207000*x))",
],
}

ceresSolve(jsonSystem) //Call the function
```

Answer (score 1):

Try **math.js**

http://mathjs.org/

It allows you to do mathematical functions in a much cleaner look.

Comment: It can solve linear systems using [`usolve`](https://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/usolve.html), but I don't see a solver for polynomial equations.

Comment: @AndersonGreen How about https://algebra.js.org/ then? Although given the question is over two years old it's probably too late.